# There must be a better old question for "I lost my iPhone, now what do I do?"

Tags: discussion

Upon reaching this new question, ["What actions can be taken with lost and locked phone?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193199/what-actions-can-be-taken-with-lost-and-locked-phone) I followed the duplicate question link to ["Lost iPhone, what action to take?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/lost-iphone-what-action-to-take) and read the answer and followed the links.

What? Really?  the answer is 4 years old, uses out of date terminology, has a broken apple link, and mobileMe links (that do forward to iCloud.com at least).

Comment: I agree, the question needs a version more suitable for 2015. Do you want to volunteer to write one?